# Convert this algorithm into a procedure, that doesn't use recursion

Tags: algorithm, function, haskell, functional-programming, ocaml

Few weeks ago I had a task to accomplish and my way of thinking is correct, but the implementation I gave at that time was horrible. I have a chance to get some points but only if I provide a correct implementation.
The problem is:

> Consider a list of integers [x_1; x_2;...;x_n]. We'll call index i "a hole"
>   if 1 < i < n, such as x_i < max(x_1,...,x_{i-1}) and x_i < max(x_{i+1},...,x_n).
>   The depth of this hole is min(max(x_1,...,x_{i-1})-x_i, max(x_{i+1},...,x_n)-x_i).
>
> Write procedure `hole : int list -> int` which for given list of integers find the max depth on this list. If there is no hole on the list, then the correct answer is 0. For example: `hole [5;2;7;10;3;7] = 3`, because for i=2, max on the left is 5, max on the right is 10, min (5 - 2, 10-2) = 3. `hole [1;2;3;2;1] = 0`, because there is no such index i, that matches our predicate.

Now, my procedure looks like this with using recursion:

```
let hole list =
   let rec aux maxL acc = function
    | [] -> (min_int, [])
    | x::xs ->
        let newMax = max maxL x in
        let (maxR, aclist) = aux newMax acc xs
        in
            if maxL > x && x < maxR then (max maxR x,(min (maxL-x) (maxR-x))::aclist)
            else (max maxR x, aclist)
in fold_left max 0 (snd (aux min_int [] list))
```

but I have to make it without using recursion, while I'm able to use high order functions.
I wanted to use something called "function accumulation", but I can't get any idea on how to do it (been thinking about this problem for over 7 hours now).

Any code given in Haskell/OCaml is welcome. The only problem is that you CANNOT use recursion.

Comment: I am still considering that list.  Was there something you wanted me to do with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I can't understand from the snippet of the problem what the function is supposed to do or even what type it should have. The provided code is supposedly not a "correct implementation". Can you please describe the function you are looking for, and perhaps include some sample inputs and the corresponding result?

Comment: "Write procedure "hole : int list -> int" which for given list of integers find the max depth on this list. If there is no hole on the list, then the correct answer is 0.
For example: hole [5;2;7;10;3;7] = 3, because for i=2, max on the left is 5, max on the right is 10, min (5 - 2, 10-2) = 3.
hole [1;2;3;2;1] = 0, because there is no such index i, that matches our predicate.

Comment: Isn't the `3` at position 5 in your list a deeper hole?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that may do what I think you are looking for, i.e. find the *depth of* the deepest 'hole' in a list of integers according to your description of a 'hole'. It zips up left and right scans for max with a list of the 'middle' values, which could be described with the word 'accumulating' if you want.

Not the most efficient implementation, I'm sure, but I think it is better than the obvious brute force solution. Where no hole is found, it returns `Nothing`.

```hs
deepestHole' :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
deepestHole' xs 
  | length xs < 3 = Nothing
  | maxHole < 1 = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just maxHole
  where
    lMaxes = scanl1 max $ take (length xs - 2) xs
    rMaxes = scanr1 max (drop 2 xs)
    middles = tail $ init xs
    holeDepth lMax mid rMax = min lMax rMax - mid
    maxHole = maximum $ zipWith3 holeDepth lMaxes middles rMaxes
```